# Alternative way to obtain WIFI readings in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, wifi

I worked on Android project to get wifi info, such as: rssi, ssid, mac..

I want to do same that on windows phone 8, but unfortunately not allowed to access to its API in windows phone!

There is any alternative idea to get wifi info in windows 8? in other word: can I read wifi info without using this API?

This topic is very impotent for me and for other developers, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to get the WiFi SSID information on windows Phone from an app.

You can retrieve device networking information but not specific details for WiFi.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation(v=vs.105).aspx

You can launch the WiFi settings from your app
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Windows Phone 8.1. This is a new API available to apps, but it is being introduced in Windows 10.

I know it isn't the answer you want to hear, but here is a link to the API (says availability is 10 only) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.wifi.aspx